# Create a selection inside blackberry TextField

Tags: blackberry

How to create a selection for only a certain number of characters inside a TextField programmatically in blackberry? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details about your programming project?  What language are you using?  Is the TextField you refer to `java.awt.TextField`?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn, unless otherwise specified, **BlackBerry** is assumed to mean the BlackBerry Java platform, which is where the `TextField` class is available. BlackBerry does not have AWT. The `TextField` is a RIM-specific UI class.

Comment: @Eris, do you want to actually **select** only a few characters (for example, to support **copying** only those characters), or do you just want it to *look* like a few characters in the field are selected?

Comment: @Nate, actually i want to create a link for that specific characters, so that user can click (or enter) to go to other screen. I have successfully hooked it up to specific FieldChangeListener so user can click, but i need a way to tell user that there is a link in there, the easiest way for this i thought to create automatic selection for those characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following steps should work, assuming `myTextField` is a [TextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TextField.html) instance.

1. Call `myTextField.select(true)` method, to turn on selection mode.
2. Call `myTextField.setCursorPosition(int)` to set cursor position to the selection start
3. Use [EventInjector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventInjector.html) to inject keystrokes to emulate "select" action. Keystrokes are described in [TextField class javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TextField.html)
4. Move cursor via aforementioned `setCursorPositionMethod(int)` to expand selection area.

That's it.